# Calculate : $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k+1}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Calculate : $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k+1}{k!}$

I'm having an embarrassingly bad time trying to prove that this converges to $2e$ and I have an exam tomorrow where "a similar excercise" will appear, as per the teacher. We can use content from series (calculus 3).

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{k+1}{k!}=\frac{k}{k!}+\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}+\frac{1}{k!}$$

Can you continue?

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates.

Comment: I posted before I saw it was a duplicate

Comment: It is useful to look for duplicates before answering a question in the case that is highly probable that there is (are) duplicate(s). You can use for example Approach0.